# TypeError: Cannot read property 'salida' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I get an error, which I interpret happens because the method I try to call or invoke does not exist. The strange thing or strange of all this, is that I use the same way to inject the service, and that error does not occur, well without further preamble, I will place the code and the explanation.

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'salida' of undefined at new mostrarPerfilEstu
```

### historial.js

```
  angular.module('historialApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'horarioEstudiante', 'calificacionesEstudiante'])    
           .controller('borrarHistorial', borrarHistorial)
           .factory('salirApp', salirApp);

    salirApp.$inject = ['$ionicPlatform', '$ionicHistory', '$timeout', '$cordovaSQLite'];

function salirApp($ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $timeout, $cordovaSQLite) {

    function salida() {

        var BackButton = 0;

        $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {            

            if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'menuestu' || $ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'menuprof') {

                if (BackButton === 0) {

                    BackButton++;
                    window.plugins.toast.showLongCenter("Presione nuevamente para salir");

                    $timeout(function() {
                        BackButton = 0;
                    }, 2500);

                } else {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }

            } else {
                if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() == 'login') {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                } else {
                    $ionicHistory.goBack();
                }
            }

        }, 100);

    }

    return {
        salida: salida
    };

}
```

In this file I have a `factory`, which, when I inject the module into another, and call the method, when I need it.

#### horarioestu.js

```
angular.module('horarioEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'btford.socket-io', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('mostrarHorarioEstu', mostrarHorarioEstu);


mostrarHorarioEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerHorarioEstu', 'socket', 'salirApp'];

function mostrarHorarioEstu($scope, obtenerHorarioEstu, socket, salirApp) { 

    salirApp.salida();

}
```

In the above code, I inject the module, to call the **factory** `exitApp`, and then invoke the `output` method.

#### perfilestu.js

```
angular.module('perfilEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('mostrarPerfilEstu', mostrarPerfilEstu);

mostrarPerfilEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfilEstu', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFile', 'salirApp'];

function mostrarPerfilEstu($scope, obtenerPerfilEstu, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, salirApp, $element) {   

    salirApp.salida();

}
```

In the code previously exposed in the file perfilestu.js, I throw error, the rarest thing is that I invoke it in the same way and it appears that error only in this and not in the other 5 options of the app.

Comment: Could you remove the last parameter of mostrarPerfilEstu(), $element, and try again?

Comment: I solved, dont remove, just change the position, i put above the `salirApp, $element`, just copy the work code, and i haved incorrect position. Thnaks